# Let $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \| x_{n+1} - x_{n} \| $ converges, then $ x_n $ is a fundamental sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \| x_{n+1} - x_{n} \| $ converges, then $ \{x_n\}_{n = 0}^\infty $ is a fundamental sequence?

Comment: For large $A,B$ you have $\epsilon>\sum_{n=A}^{B}\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|\geq\|\sum_{n=A}^{B}(x_{n+1}-x_n)\|=\|x_{B+1}-x_A\|$.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! People here prefer that the questions asked have some context behind them. What have you tried? Why does this interest you? You can add this info in an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3487373/edit).

Comment: What is a fundamental sequence?

Comment: That is **Cauchy sequence**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since for all $n>m\geq M$:
$$\|x_m-x_n\|\leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|\leq \sum_{k=M}^\infty \|x_{k+1}-x_k\|$$
and this tail sum goes to zero as $M \to \infty$.